# TS2722 in combination with strict parameter in tsconfig

Tags: typescript

I'm aware that these errors have arisen due to the `strictNullChecks` parameter, which is enabled by the `strict` setting in the `tsconfig.json` file. However, it seems logical that if `arguments.length === 2`, the `ab` function does exist (bcs Function Overloading). So, why is the error occurring? Do you have any suggestions for improving the code or resolving the issue?

### 15 errors inside `switch`

> TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly  undefined

### my `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ESNext"
  }
}
```

```js
function Σ<A>(a: A): A;
function Σ<A, B>(a: A, ab: (a: A) => B): B;
function Σ<A, B, C>(a: A, ab: (a: A) => B, bc: (b: B) => C): C;
function Σ<A, B, C, D>(a: A, ab: (a: A) => B, bc: (b: B) => C, cd: (c: C) => D): D;
function Σ<A, B, C, D, E>(a: A, ab: (a: A) => B, bc: (b: B) => C, cd: (c: C) => D, de: (d: D) => E): E;
function Σ<A, B, C, D, E, F>(
  a: A,
  ab: (a: A) => B,
  bc: (b: B) => C,
  cd: (c: C) => D,
  de: (d: D) => E,
  ef: (e: E) => F
): F;
function Σ(a: unknown, ab?: Function, bc?: Function, cd?: Function, de?: Function, ef?: Function): unknown {
  switch (arguments.length) {
    case 1:
      return a;
    case 2:
      return ab(a);
    case 3:
      return bc(ab(a));
    case 4:
      return cd(bc(ab(a)));
    case 5:
      return de(cd(bc(ab(a))));
    case 6:
      return ef(de(cd(bc(ab(a)))));
  }
}
```

[PLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&module=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABIYuAA8BBAfACgIYC5F0BKQ9AbgChRJYEUMAaRAIRwKOdwCNC8ziiALyZWpVlRrR4SNOmYtmAYXZkuvRPyKCRrZtwh8NLHaKXilk8NPpyFy5gBFVnRDz4cSw0YsQGjhCbeiErMEAAmfIYhpoiO4o5WtDIM8nohTswAoi5p7pqesb7%20msaxoYgRUYTmwY7M4QCmfJFxsVniWUk2skzpFfWIWcwAYjiUiG5qE24aWl66ijMl2GXBoTNVmtG1uvUzTS2E8cHDM43AfM1DsSOU4iPddLJa4ADWYHAA7mDqAPyEEbWZ76CAAxBA5IIMLhcGQnoNRpw4EyZgXZFQsDid6fH6IADeMwAzl8YFAIAALAoAJwA5iAALaNMBQIkAOgANszaVAKYJCZNJhBcETGogAIz4GaCxDUxpQEDUpC4Kgy4WixAAJilMsmcoVStmeGIqsF6rFAGYdbr9YqkAY8NxjSbpZURWKACzWmW2w0RVYQR3Ol1q92IACs3sFvqQTWw-odPGDIbNYYAbFG9fK7YgLtg4wnA0ncMRS6XTQBfSgVoA)

Comment: TS doesn't see `arguments` as a type guard on the actual arguments; if you need control flow like this I'm pretty sure [this version](shttps://tsplay.dev/Nap16w) is the only way to do it, but why do you want control flow like that instead of a [reduce operation](https://tsplay.dev/mxyDXW)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach uses function overloading to ensure type safety for all overloads. I am using a spread operator to collect all provided function args and applies each function iteratively.

**Heres how i would approach it**:

```
function Σ<A>(a: A): A;
function Σ<A, B>(a: A, ab: (a: A) => B): B;
function Σ<A, B, C>(a: A, ab: (a: A) => B, bc: (b: B) => C): C;
function Σ<A, B, C, D>(a: A, ab: (a: A) => B, bc: (b: B) => C, cd: (c: C) => D): D;
function Σ<A, B, C, D, E>(a: A, ab: (a: A) => B, bc: (b: B) => C, cd: (c: C) => D, de: (d: D) => E): E;
function Σ<A, B, C, D, E, F>(
  a: A,
  ab: (a: A) => B,
  bc: (b: B) => C,
  cd: (c: C) => D,
  de: (d: D) => E,
  ef: (e: E) => F
): F;

function Σ(a: unknown, ...funcs: Function[]): unknown {
  return funcs.reduce((prev, currFunc) => currFunc(prev), a);
}

// Test Cases
const a = 5;
console.log(Σ(a));  // Outputs: 5

const ab = (x: number) => x * 2;
console.log(Σ(a, ab));  // Outputs: 10

const bc = (x: number) => `Value: ${x}`;
console.log(Σ(a, ab, bc));  // Outputs: "Value: 10"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&module=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABIYuAA8BBAfACgIYC5F0BKQ9AbgChRJYEUMAaRAIRwKOdwCNC8ziiALyZWpVlRrR4SNOmYtmAYXZkuvRPyKCRrZtwh8NLHaKXilk8NPpyFy5gBFVnRDz4cSw0YsQGjhCbeiErMEAAmfIYhpoiO4o5WtDIM8nohTswAoi5p7pqesb7%20msaxoYgRUYTmwY7M4QCmfJFxsVniWUk2skzpFfWIWcwAYjiUiG5qE24aWl66ijMl2GXBoTNVmtG1uvUzTS2E8cHDM43AfM1DsSOU4iNU1NZ0slrgANZgcADuYMwAOiBUgAzoQRi8ZABtAC64k%203z%20iAA3jMAE6NKAgNFIUEAjHhEAQRrYbAABwxADcwti0RDILEILT6RByVTiFxiFQAL6USgAen5iAAKo0QVAQrgQWLKBAEOK3MJEABWKhysAguAAG0aAK1cAA5thkHhiFzJoLEAB5EBQMm2sEqvnqhU8JXYAAehDAIAAttxGmjYh7EAAqRAAJjV8u1uv1RpNuHUZvIFqFNrtDsIAEYAAzO%20USgzur2IH3%20wOxAAGADVcFqQNcACTIj3cqvRjWxvWG414dT6CAptPW232qCOgBEdYb1zzk8oQA)